# Custom js added with drupal_add_js doesn't actually get added if I enable "Aggregate JavaScript files" or "Cache blocks"

Tags: 7, css-js-aggregation

The site is the most stock, only Drupal 7 core is installed.

included my theme, where the page.tpl and html.tpl theme files are copied from core

I created a Yandex.Maps module, this is a block where js is added.

```
<?php
  function yamap_block_info(): array {
    $blocks['yamap'] = [
      'info'  => 'Block Yandex.Map',
      'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE,
    ];
    return $blocks;
  }
  
  function yamap_theme(): array {
    return [
      'main-yamap' => [
        'template' => 'yamap-block',
      ],
    ];
  }
  
  function yamap_block_view($delta = ''): array {
    if ($delta == 'yamap') {
      $module_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'yamap');
      drupal_add_js($module_path . '/src/js/yamap.js', ['scope' => 'footer', 'weight' => 40]);
      drupal_add_css($module_path . '/src/css/yamap.css');
      
      
      return [
        'content' => theme('main-yamap'),
      ];
    }
  }
?>
```

When I enable cache and aggregation, js falls off .. there are no errors on the page and in the console.

Drupal.settings.my_data does not exist too. But, if I turn off the block cache or aggregation, then everything is ok

Answer (score -1):

Is the site in D7 or D8/9?

Because in 8+ you should [use  #attached](https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-module#block) instead of drupal_add_js/css

Comment: Site build on drupal 7

Comment: I will try to use #attached